# Is it possible to disable window moving on changing it size in XNA game?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm changing the window size in that way:

```
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)i_NewSize.X;
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)i_NewSize.Y;
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges();
```

Comment: What do you mean by disable the window moving?

Comment: Do You mean moving from the top left coordinate?

Comment: I mean, when I call for a code above at runtime, not only window size changes, but also window moves (it positions the window to be in the center of sceen), I want to disable that moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, get the Form object from the window handle, save the position, change the settings, and then reposition the window.

Something like this:

```
var form = Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
var location = form.Location;
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)i_NewSize.X;
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)i_NewSize.Y;
m_GraphicsDeviceManager.ApplyChanges();
form.Location = location;
```

I haven't tested this, so no guarantees :)